How to evaluate text-to-speech models in WL
There are a many solid options for text-to-speech (TTS) now in SpeechSythesize and from API providers in general. How might I use Mathematica to compare the quality of these TTS systems available?
Seems like something NetMeasurements would handle but I don't see any vocoders or TTS models on the neural network repository.
I'm sure there's a bunch of resources and little hanging fruit here that someone can guide me to!
